# Regex sub text block with exact string at the beginning of an expression (python)

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a pattern that replaces a text block based on a start and end flag.

```
r'^(%s?.*?%s?)' % (start, stop), re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL
```

This works, but there is a conflict in the start variable.
The naming convention is name, name.001 (for duplicates)

My expression matches `'name.001'` for `'name'`, meaning that it overwrites the wrong piece of text.

How can I limit `%s?` so if I pass it `'name'`, it won't match `name.001`?

Comment: `How can I limit %s? so if I pass it 'name', it won't match name.001?` Can you rephrase this ?

Comment: What are typical `start` and `stop` values and what is the sample text you are searching?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if I've answered your question, you may accept it by clicking the checkmark next to my answer and it will give you +2 to your rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute your first `?` with a negative lookahead: `(?!\.\d{3})` -

```
re.findall(r'^(%s(?!\.\d{3}).*?%s)' % ('foo', 'bar'), 
           '''foo.001bar\nfoo2 bar\nfoo bar''', 
           re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
```

returns:

```
['foo2 bar', 'foo bar']
```

Comment: It seems to be the good way, however you must escape the dot in the negative lookahead.

Comment: This works, but I realize now that my users could potentially break the system by manually renaming the blocks things like name, nametwo. is there a more generic form of this lookahead that I can use to prevent this? I can't just check for a space, because the names are followed by a (): , for ex: name(): , name.001(): , nametwo():    ~Thanks!

Comment: @cubedparadox that's not very clear, I think you need to open a new question, state that you misspecified this one, link back to it, and be very careful to specify exactly what you need, perhaps a bit about why you need it, and be very specific as to how broad or narrow you need your expressions to be. I recommend you accept this one, as I did answer your question, and it will give you +2 to your rep.